# Microsoft Graph - Building commercial applications - Authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api

** Edit - Based on further questoins **

I'm writing a c# application, that uses ConfidentialClientApplication.  I have set up the application in azure and can connect and get a token.

The software will in fact, reside on a server, it will look something like this:

- A backend process will query the mailbox and get either a) A list of messages or b) the first message available
- It will download hte message and strip any attachments for further processing
- Once the processing is complete, it will need to move the mail to a folder, so that it is not processed again

I want to be able to pass the application, the mailbox name and the password to connect to it, a bit like POP3/IMAP.  So far, I can get a token, but anything beyond that, just barks that it doesnt have access, quite rightly.

So how do I take this one step further, and either:

- Grant the application access to a specific mailbox using azure portal
  or
- Configure the application to read the mailbox from a settings file and connect to it?

Many thanks!

Tirm

Comment: You tried your best to explain but still, there is some confusion left.   
It will be much better if you try to be more clear by using bullet points and ideally, sharing the link of any helpful content or image if any.

Comment: Hello, what you describe sounds a lot like a multi-tenant application. If your app runs as a native app (installed on user device/JS app in browser), then you do have to do interactive authentication. This does not apply to confidential applications such as those running on a server. You could build your app so you have a back-end component that requires Application permissions to do the things it needs to do. An admin from a tenant would then need to go through the authorization for the app once and then your app could access their tenant with its credentials.

Comment: Thank you both.  Ateeb, I will try and explain.  Juunas, your spot on, can we explore that a little bit further?

I have edited hte post with some additional informatoin.

Comment: I am not familiar with `ConfidentialClientApplication` only with the two ways of getting access described in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview).
Basically there are two ways to gain access (on-behalf of a user and without a user).
For deployment on a server I would suggest to get `access without a user`.
If you really do not want, that your app will have access to other users mailboxes 
then the only other option will be to gain access `on behalf of a user`.

Comment: I would highly recommend to include the tag `microsoft-graph` there you will most likely reach more people that can help you.

Comment: I've made no progress on this at all, why so complicated??!